# egrep regular expression works within PHP, but doesn't work at unix shell - escaping issues?

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I think my problem has something to do with escaping differences between using a regex within PHP versus using it at Bash commandline.

Here is my regex that is working in PHP:

```
$emailregex = '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$';
```

So I try giving the following at commandline and it doesn't seem to match anything. 
(where `emails.txt` is a long plain text file with thousands of (possibly badly-formed) email addresses, one per line).

```
 [root@host dir]# egrep '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$' emails.txt
```

I have tried surrounding the regex with double-quotemarks instead of single-quotemarks, but it made no difference.
Do I need to add some backslashes into the regex?

SOLVED! Thank you!
My file was created in Windows and extra CR in the END-OF-LINE markers did not agree with the dollar sign in the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single quotes should work with bash...

It works for me with this simple case:

```
echo test@test.com | egrep '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$'
```

In your text file, the line has to only contain the email address.  Any additional spaces on the line will throw it off.  For example this doesn't print anything:

```
echo " test@test.com" | egrep '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$'
```

Your problem might be that you have a dos formatted file.  In that case the extra `\r` will make it so that the regex doesn't match since it will think there's an extra character at the end of the line.  You can run `dos2unix` against it, or make your regex less restrictive by removing the beginning and end markers from your regex:

```
egrep '[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})'
```

Comment: OMG, THANK YOU! Removing the end of line marker ($) worked! Yes the file was created in Windows Notepad++ and FTP-ed into the *nix box.

Answer (score 1):

WWorks for me:

```
JPP-MacBookPro-4:tmp jpp$ cat emails.txt
aa@bb.com
bb@cc.com
not an email
cc@dd.ee.ff

JPP-MacBookPro-4:tmp jpp$ egrep '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,6})$' emails.txt
aa@bb.com
bb@cc.com
cc@dd.ee.ff
JPP-MacBookPro-4:tmp jpp$
```

Beware trailing whitespace/tabs/and returns - they have a way of biting regexs

There is a great ref on shell quoting here http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~uwe/lehre/unixffb/quoting-guide.html